# Two percentage surrounding a number as a variable?

Tags: batch-file

In Batch, I saw my company code had a snippet ARG1 = "%1%". But what does this mean? %1 would designate the first input command, but the extra percent either seems like bad coding practice or something so hidden that nobody knows (the only answer I got was system variables, but "1" seems like a horrible name for that).

Comment: considering it's batch, I guess the code you saw was `set arg1="%1%"` (without spaces around the `=`). You are right, `%1%` would be interpreted as `%1` (first parameter), followed by a single `%`, which the interpreter ignores because it doesn't find a second `%` to close a variable name. It's working (because the interpreter "corrects" it (sort of)), but syntactically wrong (should probably be `set ARG1="%1"`, which is still bad coding practice - hard to decide without seeing the context (aka "more code"))

Comment: Assuming @Stephan is right it is completely unnecessary. `%1` is there to be used, it is pointless and slow to assign it to another variable, which means the environment block will need to be sorted. This details some punctuation characters you may see in a batch file https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/12/command-prompt-cheat-sheet.html.

Comment: Well, the best way is `set "ARG1=%~1"`, which removes potential quoting first (due to `~`), and then assigns the value to the variable `ARG1` without any quotation (note the position of the opening `"`); something like `set ARG1="%~1"` would include the quotes in the variable value, which is nasty to handle (imagine you want to join two values: how would the following look like when the individual values were quoted? for instance, `D:\%FDIR%\%FNAME%`)...

Comment: @Stephan - Why a comment instead of an answer? There is no way to accept a comment, and it seems silly to not have this question answered. Your comment is nearly all that could be said for an answer, except for perhaps the added info in the aschipfl comment.

Comment: @dbenham: added it as "Community wiki" - too much input from others to claim possible upvotes alone.

Answer (score 1):

Considering we are talking about batch, I guess the code you saw was `set arg1="%1%"` (without spaces around the `=`).

You are correct, `%1%` would be interpreted as `%1` (the first argument/parameter to the batch file), followed by a single `%`, which the interpreter ignores because it doesn't find a second `%` to close a variable name.  (*Note 2*)

It's working (because the interpreter "corrects" it (sort of - *Note 2*)), but syntactically wrong (should probably be `set ARG1="%1"`, which is still bad coding practice (*Note 1*) - but that's hard to decide without seeing the context (aka "more code"))

---

Note 1: (well described by @aschipfl): The best (and recommended) way is `set "ARG1=%~1"`, which removes potential quoting first (due to ~), and then assigns the value to the variable `ARG1` without any quotation (note the position of the opening `"`); something like `set ARG1="%~1"` would include the quotes in the variable value, which is nasty to handle (imagine you want to join two values: how would the following look like when the individual values were quoted? for instance, `D:\%FDIR%\%FNAME%`) (don't use quoted values - put the quotes where they are needed instead)

Note 2: Don't rely on that; something like `set combined=%1%-%2%` with a first parameter of `alpha` and a second one with `beta` would be interpreted as `alpha2` (first argument `%1`, a (probably undefined) variable `%-%`, a literal `2` and an orphaned `%`, which gets ignored)

Note 3: (as commented by @Mark) setting the parameter to a variable is not necessary in the most cases, you can always reference it by `%1` or `%~1` (as needed) The only time you need an additional variable is when you want to do substring manipulation with it (that doesn't work with `%1`)